# ArcGIS gdb table field name problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes, append

I used a tool to draw a polyline following specified point objects. A new feature class was automatically created and the new polyline is a row in that table. This data is stored in my personal disk in my PC.

Then I need to import the polyline into an existing feature class in the GDB. "Append" should work fine but there is a problem with the field names. The existing target table has a field "SHAPE.LEN" and my new feature class consisting of the new polyline has a field "Shape_Length".

The Append doesn't work because of this. I tried to create a new field with the same name in the new table but a dot is not an eligible character in a field name (I don't know how it can be in the name of the existing table).

I tried Append in a replica of this database and it worked fine as for some reason in the replica the field name of the existing table matches the name of my new table.

Any ideas how to figure this out? I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 with a GDB.

Comment: I assume both feature classes are polyline: Start editing on the existing feature class, right click the newly created polyline and click Copy, right click somewhere else on the map and paste.

Comment: Thanks, it works! The solution was apparently too simple so I didn't realize it :)

Answer (score 1):

Start editing on the existing feature class, right click the newly created polyline and click Copy, right click somewhere else on the map and paste.